# Save BLOB to disk as Image C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms, blob

I am developing a web application that calls web services developed by a third party to send/receive data from a clients database. I am building the application using ASP.NET 3.5 C#.

The way that they are providing me images is in BLOB format. I call their method and what I get back is a DataSet with 2 fields "logo_name" and "logo" which is the BLOB field.
 What I want to do is: Save the image locally on the disk (to minimize calls to their database in the future).

I have been playing around with a couple of different ways of doing this but cannot seem to get the image to save correctly. I have been able to create a file in a folder with the correct name but if I try to view the image it does not work.

I was hoping someone could give me some sample code to show me how to save a BLOB field to the local disk?

Here is the code I currently have

```
public static class ProductImages
    {


        public static string GetSchoolLogo(string schoolID, string printCodeID)
        {
            int v_length = 0;
            string v_file_name = "";
            byte[] v_file_data = null;

            try
            {

                //Declare Web Service Variables
                P_SERVICE.Service ldeService = new P_SERVICE.Service();
                //Authentication Header
                ldeService.AuthHeaderValue = CGlobal.GetAuthHeader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session);
                P_SERVICE.CDataResultOfDataSet ldeResult = null;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                ldeResult = ldeService.GetItemLogo(schoolID, printCodeID);
                ds = ldeResult.Value;

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    v_file_data = StrToByteArray(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].ToString().TrimEnd());
                    v_file_name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo_name"].ToString().TrimEnd();
                    v_length = Convert.ToInt32(v_file_data.Length);

                    // Load the file in the Memory Stream
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(v_file_data, 0, v_file_data.Length);
                    ms.Write(v_file_data, 0, v_file_data.Length);

                    // Open the file stream in ordre to save on the local disk
                    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/_imagecache/schoolLogos/").ToString();
                    FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path + schoolID + "/" + v_file_name);
                    fs.Write(v_file_data, 0, v_file_data.Length);
                    fs.Close();

                    // Return True if no errors occured
                    return "~/_imagecache/schoolLogos/" + schoolID + "/" + v_file_name;
                }
                else
                    return "~/images/noPhoto.gif";

           }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
                //return "~/images/noPhoto.gif";
            } 
        }

        // C# to convert a string to a byte array.
        public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
        {
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            return encoding.GetBytes(str);
        }
    }


}
```

When I get the Type of data being returned it returns System.String

```
Type t = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].GetType();
HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn(t.FullName);
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your current code, it may be easier to point out where the issue is than expect someone to post code for you.

Comment: Agree with Pharabus, post your code, I'm sure you have atleast started with a byte array and filestream - show us your code.

Comment: Thanks guys, my code is above.

Comment: What does a portion of `v_file_data` look like? perhaps it is base64?
Are you sure it is coming in as a string? Also tell us what `ds.Tables[0].Columns["logo"].DataType` returns and we can clear up some abiguity.

Comment: A portion of the 'logo' column in the returned dataset looks like this:

@’Ïû3ìÒÇ<~awl†ìGù=…tC–²¼%÷™•¹t’þ½ ¸ý¨|fo¥‚ *ÎH÷ì@!bÍƒßôíYU£R Þvù+ªÑNÍ~?ðGûPøìJb“ÃÖÄ‚bÀêÊqž§¹úV6—*µUóµ¿48ÎŒµQ¿£ÿ�€týª®µ RËIÕ|6RIæ™c›$ãî•õ#½Zöñ×™5èÿ�ÿÛ�„�


Sorry if that is not what you mean. All this is very new to me

Comment: The file is being saved in the correct location on the disk, it has a file size of 62.kb and the filename is 016-3-PR-BLGY.jpg, so everything seems to be working. All except if I try to display the image nothing shows up and if I try to open the file in a program like Adobe Fireworks I get an 'unknown file type' error. Seems like I am nearly there but missing that final piece of the puzzle!

Comment: Ok, looks like bytes. ck is heading the right direction, you don't want to treat this as a string. To be sure, though, please report back what `ds.Tables[0].Columns["logo"].DataType` returns if you break at a point after it is loaded.

Comment: Type t = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].GetType();
HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn(t.FullName);

This returns as System.String

Comment: Ummm... what does `ds.Tables[0].Columns["logo"].DataType` return. I will be honest, I usually don't ask the same question 3 times when I am trying to help someone.... and when you reply, be sure to include @sky so that it is brought to my attention.

Comment: @sky - Sorry, I appreciate the help and your patience. I am trying to find out what the DataType is but I don't know what you mean. If I try to trace ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].DataType I get an error. "'object' does not contain a definition for 'DataType' ..."

Comment: @TGuimond: not `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].DataType`, sky meant `ds.Tables[0].Columns["logo"].DataType` like he posted three times before :)

Comment: @sky,@Philip - ok, fair point :) When I trace the result of this  I still get System.String ----- HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn(ds.Tables[0].Columns["logo"].DataType.ToString());

Comment: wow. Ok, I am going to take a stab at an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like the web service is doing you no favors. They really should be returning a byte array. but anyway, the string is definitely not base64 and definitely not ascii.

Lets try this wild stab in the dark:

```
v_file_data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"]);
```

Comment: I tried that but I am getting the same result. Image file being created, correctly named and path being returned correctly but not displaying and when I try to open in any editor it gives an unknown file type error. Image size even seems correct.

Comment: @sky: Note: I added a `ToString()` as it was giving me an error without it:

`v_file_data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].ToString());`

Comment: @TGui - hint: 'an error' doesn't give much to work with. At least give the error type. Ok, so try `v_file_data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(((string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"]));`

Comment: @sky - Cheers. The error was `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(char[])' has some invalid arguments`.

Also, I tried the last line of code and am getting the same result. Image file created, correct name, etc.

Comment: @sky - I could probably ask the developers of the webservice to alter the service to give me a byte array instead.. I really appreciate the time you spent trying to figure this out for me.

Comment: @TGui - yeah, this is an odd one. You might suggest to them to also provide a usage example. I don't let a bit out the door without a working skeleton example. It is just bad form. Good luck.

Comment: @sky - The developers finally came back with a working example and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Your line:

```
v_file_data = StrToByteArray(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].ToString().TrimEnd());
```

Should really be:

```
v_file_data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"] as Byte[];
```

The method you were using will not encode and decode the bytes in the same way.

Comment: Granted, the StrToByteArray is hinky, but perhaps the image is coming in Base64?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// replace this line:
//v_file_data = StrToByteArray(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].ToString().TrimEnd());

// with this block:
string base64string = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"] as string;

if (base64string != null)
{
    v_file_data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(v_file_data);
}
```

Take the byte array and load it to file using the rest of your code.

HTH....